# How do I configure a Cisco router to relay DHCP packets to DHCP server on the basis of different VLAN?

Tags: vlan, ipv4, dhcp

**Running-Config of RO1**

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.25.26 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.15
 encapsulation dot1Q 15
 ip address 192.168.15.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.25.25
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.25.25
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**Running-Config of RO2**

```
sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 976 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.15.1 192.168.15.2
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.2
!
ip dhcp pool vlan15
 network 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.15.1
ip dhcp pool vlan20
 network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.20.1
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524KMR9-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.25.25 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**The topology is given below**
[image]

What am I still missing out that RO2 is not leasing ip addresses to PC-A and PC-B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DHCP config looks OK, but I don't see how RO2 could know where those subnets are actually located - RO1 might use its local subnet addresses as source for the relay packets. RO2 either requires a default route via 192.168.25.26 or - better - specific routes for 192.168.15.0/24 and 192.168.20.0/24.

Alternatively, you could set up a routing protocol like OSPF between the routers.

And of course, the switch ports need to be configured correctly as well.